Impedance controlled PCB for USB 2.0?
We're doing a PCB for a customer that has Impedance controlled tracks for a microcontroller that seemingly might be max USB2.0, judging from lack of multiple data lines and the fact it goes in a micro-usb connector. The data lines are made naturally with differential pair.
We're doing the board buildup according to the specified 100ohm impedance, but I was still wondering, is it really required at these speeds? As far as I remember the data line for USB2.0 is like 240MHz, so not really in the GHz ranges.

Have you come across the concept of signal reflections causing data errors?

Impedance control is as necessary as any other high-speed application, in relation to the signal levels and thresholds / eye diagram, and the bit rate to the length of impedance mismatch/discontinuity in question. What trace lengths will you board use?

USB2 signals definitely extend up past 1 GHz.

@TimWilliams 67 millimeters
